# Replacing a function by a macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I was trying to clean up some code by replacing some functions by macros, and then call this new macros from inside another macro in C.

My original code was:

```
int min(int x,int y){return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));}
int max(int x,int y){return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));}
#define UTOP(x) ((v[b[2]][0] * min((x) + 1, b[0])) + (v[b[2]][1] * max(0, (x) + 1 - b[0])))
#define UBOT(x) ((v[b[2]][0] * min((x), b[0])) + (v[b[2]][1] * max(0, (x) - b[0])))
```

This code works fine. Note that v[][] and b[] are global variables (containing integers), and x is always an integer number.

When I replace the previous code by:

```
#define MIN(a,b) ((a) ^ (((b) ^ (a)) & -((a) < (b))))
#define MAX(a,b) ((b) ^ (((a) ^ (b)) & -((b) < (a))))
#define UTOP(x) ((v[b[2]][0] * MIN(((x) + 1), (b[0]))) + (v[b[2]][1] * MAX(0, ((x) + 1 - b[0]))))
#define UBOT(x) ((v[b[2]][0] * MIN((x), (b[0]))) + (v[b[2]][1] * MAX(0, ((x) - b[0]))))
```

Macros UTOP and UBOT return unexpected results. I've already roam SO for an explanation but found no plausible solution. Any advice?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Replacing functions with macros is usually regarded as the converse of “cleaning up”.  Use static inline functions in preference to macros.

Comment: It is inadequate to describe a problem merely as “return unexpected results.” State argument values for which they evaluate to (not “return”) unexpected results, state the results they evaluate to, and state the results expected instead. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Also note that macro replacement commonly results in multiply evaluation of the arguments, whereas a function call does not, and hence macros replicate side effects contain inside the argument, such as `++` and other function calls. Function calls also convert arguments to parameter types, whereas macros do not.

Comment: I will observe that your minimum and maximum expressions are unusually complex.  I assume that the intent is to avoid a condition which might stall a pipeline.  But the lack of clarity probably outweighs the benefit.  IMO, you'd need to be able to demonstrate the performance benefit to warrant using the circumlocuitous expressions.

Comment: "I was trying to clean up some code by replacing some functions by macros"  You are doing the opposite: turning already messy code worse. And I believe the old XOR swap trick has been dismissed as inefficient and dangerous nonsense several times...

Comment: I'd recommend you to run the C preprocessor only and to observe the result.

Comment: I think the primary goal is not to replace some function by some macro but sth the op did not told us. Please tell us what you want to achieve by the replacement procedure. Maybe we can tell you about a better way to obtain this. A common usecase for macros is to isolate some parts of some heavily repeating code and still be able to access volatile compile time definitions like e.g. __LINE__ and __FILE__ in assert macros. However, i don't see that usecase, here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I completely forgot about static inline functions, it is easy to compute the correct result with this type of functions. However I've read that the the inline keyword is simply a suggestion, and I would like to force the preprocessor to generate this code for me.

Comment: @pqans, you are right. I was trying to use macros in order to avoid calls within calls in order to obtain an efficient compiler optimization. I've read somewhere this is the reason why compilers struggle to optimize recursive functions.

Comment: At least for the xor-min, your optimization is counter-productive: https://gist.github.com/ghpqans/7398f6c24798fd4b4f2c49f409289739. Below you find the UTOP assembly for the recursive function version and the macro version. As you can see there is minor difference and the optimizer produces inlined code, anyway.

Comment: @pqans, Thank you for the insight. Guess I'll go with the least cryptic solution. Guess I'll also go with the static inline solutions, due to readibility.

Answer (score 2):

The `MIN` and `MAX` macros are not equivalent to the `min` and `max` functions. Aside from needlessly changing the parameter names, they use them differently; some of the operands have been inadvertently switched.

For `int min(int x,int y){return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));}`, the macro should not be:

```
#define MIN(a,b) ((a) ^ (((b) ^ (a)) & -((a) < (b))))
```

but rather:

```
#define MIN(a,b) ((b) ^ (((a) ^ (b)) & -((a) < (b))))
```

or preferably:

```
#define MIN(x, y) ((y) ^ (((x) ^ (y)) & -((x) < (y))))
```

The latter could have been prepared with simple text editing (such as pattern substitutions), avoiding any human error in renaming or retyping.

Similarly, the replacement for `int max(int x,int y){return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));}` should not be:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((b) ^ (((a) ^ (b)) & -((b) < (a))))
```

but rather:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a) ^ (((a) ^ (b)) & -((a) < (b))))
```

or preferably:

```
#define MAX(x, y) ((x) ^ (((x) ^ (y)) & -((x) < (y))))
```

Further, unless the code is using a compiler and targeting a processor for which it is known that the above generates efficient code and the alternative below does not, then the alternative below should be used for clarity and portability:

```
#define MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
#define MAX(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (y) : (x))
```

Comment: Another difference between the functions and any of the macro variations presented is that the macros each evaluate at least one of their arguments more than once.  This will produce different behavior than the functions do when the argument expressions have side effects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried your solution without success. Even with the least cryptic approach ```#define MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))```. I think my problem has something to do with argument passing within the macro, I just wasn't able to pinpoint it so far.